# Create multiple PDF's based on user selections- paginated report in report builder

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

We have a report that has a drop down list of 50 countries, based on the user selection, say the user selects 10 countries, 10 sets of information comes up one for each country.

What I need is based on grouping of each country

1. Report view showing one country detail separated by page  break.  So at least 10 pages.
2. When exported or printed or saved, there will be 10 different PDF's named by country name.  So 10 pdf's.

Is that something doable in power BI paginated reports under report builder? I am more interested in knowing if 10 pds's can be created upon export based on group selected.

Thanks

-Sarah